# Logical operator in filter dplyr on non numeric

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I use & | to compare strings in filter?

```
AP = df1 %>%
    filter( x == "AP" | "AC") %>% 
    group_by(y) %>% 
    summarise(Z = sum(Z))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I provide you an example with the `iris` data:

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
AP = iris %>%
  filter( Species == "setosa" | Species =="virginica")
```

Remember to repeat the variable name :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing multiple `|` statements, you could also use `%in%`:

```
AP = df1 %>%
  filter(x %in% c("AP","AC")) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  summarise(Z = sum(Z))
```